# Default propagation beahaviour for @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have the following code :

```java
@Component
public class A{ 

 @Transactional
 public void classa(){
     //logic
 }

}
```

I don't specify any propagation behaviour for `@Transactional` annotation. So I want to know what is the default propagation beahaviour for `@Transactional` in spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[REQUIRED](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) is the default propagation

> **REQUIRED**
>   public static final Propagation REQUIRED
>   Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists. Analogous to EJB transaction attribute of the same name.
>   This is the **default setting of a transaction annotation**.